# Click event doesn't work in IE when element has an opacity of zero

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, click, opacity

I have an  element the opacity of which I set to zero when hovered over, I also have binded a click event to this link which performs an action when clicked but this click does not work in IE, only other browsers. Is there anything I can do to make it still clickable when the opacity is zero in IE?

Thanks!

```
$("a.hover").mouseenter(function() {

             $(this).animate({opacity:0});

        });


     $("a.hover").click(function(event) {

         event.preventDefault();
         //perform other stuff/// 
     });
```

Comment: How about setting the opacity to .01?

Comment: Why don't you handle the hover effect with `CSS`?

Comment: Sounds unlogical to me. Why should a user click on a non-visible element?

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="hover">My Link</a>
```

CSS:

```
.hover {
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
.hover:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$("a.hover").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //perform other stuff/// 
});
```

Works fine for me in Chrome, FF and IE 8 + 9

DEMO: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/BxHB7/

Answer (score -1):

Please add transparent img in background.

Comment: the problem is that it has a background alreayd which is why I fade it out.